# How to get log volume/storage size by label with Loki?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

**Background:** I have various services, managed by different teams, sending logs to a single Loki instance. Logs carries a label `service` that corresponds to the name of the service. We are also running Prometheus and Grafana.

**Goal:** Each team has an operating budget and I would like to split the cost of operating the Loki instance + storage cost based on how much logs were generated by each service, and deduct that from each team's budget.

**What I have:** I have used the LogQL query `count by(service) (rate({environment="live"} [24h]))` with the 'Instant' query type on Grafana to get the total number of log lines, grouped by the `service` label.

**Problem:** Some service's logs are tiny whilst others are big. Attributing costs based on number of log lines is inaccurate.

**Question:** Is there a LogQL query to get the total size of logs ***in bytes***, grouped by the `service` label? If not, any suggestions for other ways to attribute costs of the logs to each team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@markalex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77993639/2317532) put me on the right tracks, and I found [this post](https://community.grafana.com/t/log-ingestion-size/74672) which also helped. Turns out `bytes_over_time` is what I've been looking for:

```
sum by(service) (bytes_over_time({environment="live"} [24h]))
```

`bytes_over_time` counts the amount of bytes used by each log stream for a given range.

Answer (score 1):

To get total length of all lines present in Loki over some period of time, you can use this query:

```
sum by (service) (
    sum_over_time(
        {environment="live"}
        | label_format length=`{{ __line__  | len }}`
        | unwrap length
    [24h])
)
```

Here:

- `` label_format length=`{{ __line__  | len }}` ``  adds label `length` with value equal to length for the whole log line.
- `unwrap length` unwraps this label into value for aggregation with `sum_over_time`

---

Please notice, that while this query provides result you described, it's only an estimation of how resources are divided between services. It doesn't account for series number per service, and I believe each series has it's own storage overhead.
*<sub>I don't know how (or even if) it can be accounted for from query or any other mean</sub>